# Detect if cURL works?

Tags: php, curl

This is the warning.

> Warning: curl_setopt_array()
>   [function.curl-setopt-array]:
>   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be
>   activated when in safe_mode or an
>   open_basedir is set in /.../file.php
>   on line 41

This is what I am using to detect cURL. If cURL isn't enabled a work around is triggered.

```
function curlEnabled() {
    if (ini_get('safe_mode') == 1)
        return 0;

    return in_array('curl', get_loaded_extensions());
}
```

I am finding it very difficult to test this function effectively do to a lack of hosting with safe mode enabled or cURL disabled.

Could someone tell me.

1. Does the function actually detect PHP safe_mode?
2. It detects whether cURL is loaded right?

Finally, how would this function be improved to catch the 'cannot be activated' error and return 0?

Answer (score 6):

That seems to work correctly with `safe_mode`.

To check CURL, you can either look for it in the loaded extensions (as you did), or simply:

```
function_exists('curl_init');
```

With regards to the error message, I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want to suppress the error message?

You can do something like:

```
$old=error_reporting(0); // turn off error reporting
// do whatever that causes errors
error_reporting($old);   // turn it back on
```

Comment: To clarify, the warning means that the curlEnabled function returned 1 and the cURL code was run - even though apparently the host has trouble running it. What I want to do is be able to detect whatever is causing this warning and whether cURL actually works without generating an error or warning. I don't mind using error suppression. It is the test that I am having trouble with.

Comment: @John Paul - Since it is a warning, the code should continue running, hence you should be able to run your test successfully.