# How to use cURL in a PHP script

Tags: php, curl

I have installed curl and am trying to use it in a PHP script but I can't seem to get it to work.

I created the following php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.google.com")
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and when I try to execute in through the command line and view the page in my browser, I get "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in 'Location of file'".

However I can run curl perfectly fine in the command line by navigating to the its location and entering commands directly into the command line.

Comment: you need install php module `php-curl` to use this function

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to install it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Comment: I checked that post out and the posts in that thread already assume you can use curl. I can't even use it in my script.

Comment: What is your OS ? Linux ? Windows ?

Answer (score 1):

You should install and enable curl extension.

### For windows

Browse and open these

```
C:\Program Files\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php4\php.ini
```

Uncomment the following line in your php.ini

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Like something below-

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

> Restart your Apache server. Check your phpinfo() and Enjoy using
>   curl() library.

### For Linux

**Ubuntu**
Open your terminal and execute the followinf command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Redhat, CentOS**

```
yum install curl
service httpd restart
```

Hope you will enjoy cURL library now.

Comment: What should I do if I'm not using an Apache server? I run the command php -S localhost:8000 and go to localhost:8000 in my browser to view the site.

Answer (score 0):

Your server doesn't have cURL enabled / installed.

To enable it, you might want to take a look at these answers on similar questions:

- [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17074237/491494)
- [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724633/491494)

Comment: The thing is that I've already done that. I can run curl perfectly fine in the command line. It's just that it doesn't recognize it in the script that I'm trying to use.

Comment: When you say command line, what do you mean? Linux command line? PHP Cli?