# cURL issue with php

Tags: php, facebook, curl

When i am tryin to manualy fetch a php page by passing URL, an exception is appearing which says

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.

but when I searched php curl in my insatllation directory, I found it there.

```
[ashish@hpproliant ~]$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php
[ashish@hpproliant ~]$ which curl
/usr/local/bin/curl
```

I have modified php.ini file where a line related to curl was commented..What do i need do do now?? Thanks

Comment: maybe restart the server..

Comment: yeah i have done that before..still its not working

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just follow the below steps, and check have you done exactly same as below:-**

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Make sure curl is enabled in the php.ini file (for me it's in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini), if you can't find this line, it might be in /etc/php5/conf.d/curl.ini. Make sure the line :

```
extension=curl.so
```

is not commented out then restart apache, so type this into putty:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

**Debug:- Check whether curl is enable in PHP or not:-**

Method 1:

```
function curlEnabled() {
    if (ini_get('safe_mode') == 1)
        return 0;

    return in_array('curl', get_loaded_extensions());
}
```

Method 2:

```
function_exists('curl_init');
```

and please print the php_info(); of your server and post it here.

Please Refer to the below links Too:-
[Detect if cURL works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866348/detect-if-curl-works)
[PHP CURL Enable Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014482/php-curl-enable-linux)

Comment: Hi Nishant..thanks for the help but the issue is 1) On My Linux   cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18-8.el5 (brewbuilder@ls20-bc2-14.build.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.1 20070105 (Red Hat 4.1.1-52)) #1 SMP Fri Jan 26 14:15:21 EST 2007                sudo apt-get install php5-curl is not working..Says         sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: also   i have made extension=curl.so enabled in my php.ini file located at  /usr/local/lib  ..   also doin which curl gives   following path  /usr/local/bin/curl  which suggests presence of curl...

Comment: http://122.166.59.161:7655/JavaBridgeTemplate621/test.php     contains phpinfo of server